# Change portion of value within an array knowing only part of string and restric

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

Before I got this answer
`preg_replace("~(?<=$str&&).*~", '7', $str);`

which is good but what if within the array I have a similar string `mary&&5` and `rosemary&&5` and I stricktly want to change only `mary&&5` and not disturb the other array, is it posible? and how?

The question before was:

```
`$array = array("josh&&3", "mary&&5", "cape&&4", "doggy&&8", etc..);`
```

and I know only the string before `&&` which is username. `$str = "mary&&";` Note that I don't know what is after `&&`

I want to know whether exist or not within the array, and if exist change the value to something new like `mary&&7`

```
   `$isExists = preg_replace("some","some", $array);
   if ($isExists){
   echo "Its exists";
   } else {
   echo "Not exixts" 
   } ;`
```

How can I change the portion of the value after && in `mary&&5` or completely change `mary&&5` to `mary&&7` since I don't know before hand the value `mary&&5`?

Thanks for your answer :)

```
    `$name = "mary";
    $res = "7";
    $str = array("josh&&3", "mary&&5", "cape&&4", "doggy&&8","rosemary&&5");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($str); ++$i) { 
    $r = preg_replace("~(?<=$name).*~",$res, $str);}`
```

Comment: Does `$str` come from `$array` in your above code snippets? Could you post your full code as one block?

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you show an example array and what you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array('josh&&3', 'mary&&5', 'cape&&4', 'doggy&&8', 'rosemary&&5');

$name = 'mary';
$number = '7';
$replacement = $name . '&&' . $number;
```

So, a way without regex:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    if (explode('&&', $v)[0] === $name)
        $arr[$k] = $replacement;
}
```

*( or you can use `strpos($v, $name . '&&') === 0` as condition)*

a way with regex:

```
$arr = preg_filter('~\A' . $name . '&&\K.*~', $number, $arr);
```

*(where `\K` removes all on the left from the match result, so the name and `&&` aren't replaced)*